# dynamic symbols with statically linked libstdc++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

I need to compile my c++ application for 32-bit platform. To support older systems I've linked libstdc++ statically. The trouble is that even with static libstdc++ gcc linker adds a lot of dynamic symbols.

Here is `nm -D` output on the compiled application:

```
08137f2c u _ZNSt7num_putIcSt19ostreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE2idE
08137fbc u _ZNSt7num_putIwSt19ostreambuf_iteratorIwSt11char_traitsIwEEE2idE
08135b24 V _ZTINSt8ios_base7failureE
08135930 V _ZTISt10bad_typeid
08134e90 V _ZTISt10moneypunctIcLb0EE
08134e70 V _ZTISt10moneypunctIcLb1EE
081354b0 V _ZTISt10moneypunctIwLb0EE
08135490 V _ZTISt10moneypunctIwLb1EE
08135b44 V _ZTISt11logic_error
08135b8c V _ZTISt11range_error
0813380c V _ZTISt11regex_error
```

And lots of other symols. Mostly they are unique global or weak objects. Below are Makefile and a simple cpp file.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "s" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
CXX         = g++
EXE         = app
CXXFLAGS    = -std=c++14 -m32
LDFLAGS     = -m32
LDLIBS      = -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc

SOURCES     = main.cpp
OBJS        = $(subst .cpp,.o,$(SOURCES))

all: $(EXE)
    strip $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(EXE)
```

Is there any way I can get rid of those symbols?
The libstdc++ I use is from last gcc (6.2.1) on Arch linux. And x64 version compiles without any additional symbols.